# Recursively rendering the same partial in rails crashes the app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to render a tree of nodes by calling the same partial recursively every time with a different node. But some how, it keeps calling the partial with the root node for an infinite number of times until the app crashes.

this is `index.html.erb`

```
    <%= render(partial: "branch", head: @head)%>
```

And this is `_branch.html.erb`

```
    <%= @head.name%>

    <%@head.children.each do |child|%>
        <%= render( partial: "branch", head: child)%>
    <%end%>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: every time you render that partial, you're looping through `@head.children`, that's a never ending loop indeed.

Comment: just change `@head` for `head`

Comment: Thanks, That was it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to render each branch, not the same `@head` over and over:

```
<%= render(partial: "branch", object: @head) %>
```

Then the partial looks like this:

```
<%= branch.name %>

<% branch.children.each do |child|%>
    <%= render( partial: "branch", head: child)%>
<% end %>
```

The name of the partial is the name of the variable representing the content.